# How to create database using Db4o in android?

Tags: android, database, db4o

I am developing an App in which now i have to create database for more better user experience. Then i came to know about DB4o which is many times faster tool for creating database than other like SQLite, MySql etc, but the problem is i am not able to find any single example that explains about DB4o and how to create database using Db4o. If anybody has used it, please post an example or send me link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To store the object in database use

```
db().store(exercise);
```

To retrieve All records from database, use

```
db().query(Object);
```

To retrieve particular record from database, use

```
db().queryByExample(Object);
```

If you need example, Try My [blog example](http://v4all123.blogspot.com/2013/12/using-db4o-in-android.html) using db4o. 
In this example, simple student object will be stored in database using `db4o`. Student `object` will contain student name, register number, and his age.

Thank you.